# App Crashes when Motion and Fitness permissions are provided after initial denial

Tags: ios, swift

I in my app is requesting user to provide motion and fitness application access to read data such as steps and others. I am currently facing an issue where if the permissions are initially denied by the user and later provided when alerted on loading of the screen.
I have added the error as an image and provided code which I am using to access pedometer class. If someone can provide me an overview about the error it will be really helpful.

```
 if(CMPedometer.isStepCountingAvailable()){
    let pedoMeter = CMPedometer()

    pedoMeter.startPedometerUpdatesFromDate(timeM) { (data, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            if(error == nil){
                self.stepsTaken.text = String((data!.numberOfSteps))
            }
            else{
                self.alertView()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you post the error?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error as text as well as the line of code the error occurs on. Linked images are not helpful as they can disappear over time.

Comment: I don't think those messages are related to your crash.  I have seen them in the past without a crash.  You should have a full stack trace for the crash, and that's what we need to see.

Comment: Ok. I m sorry for incomplete information provided. I think its just found a bug with this where app is forced to restart.

Comment: I am quite sure about it as it is even happening with health app which is developed by apple. I am writing down steps to reproduce, if you guys want to try you will feel the same:

Open health app ---->  Single tap on home button to exit --->  Go to settings ---> Privacy ---> Motion & Fitness --->  Switch off access to health

Double tap on home button to open health app --> It restarts

I am facing the same issue and this happens with two other fitness app such as pedometer++ and pacer which uses those sensors.

*Reported to Apple.

Comment: I've also filed a Radar: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6145472091652096